# Incompatible types. Fraction cannot be converted to String

Tags: java

I'm trying to complete an assignment for University. I've done all the bulk of the code, and from what I can tell, it should work. However, I keep getting an error back.

I'm not really sure what to try as I thought this was exactly how it works. I've revisited my previous lectures, done the subject readings, and reached out to my fellow students. So far, I haven't gotten a solution back.

```
private static Fraction fraction1;
private static Fraction fraction2;



public static void main(String[] args)
{

    String fraction1 = args[0];

    String[] splittedFraction1 = fraction1.split("/");

    String fraction2 = args[1];

    String[] splittedFraction2 = fraction2.split("/");



    int numerator1 = Integer.parseInt(splittedFraction1[0]);

    int denominator1 = Integer.parseInt(splittedFraction1[1]);

    int numerator2 = Integer.parseInt(splittedFraction2[0]);

    int denominator2 = Integer.parseInt(splittedFraction2[1]);


    fraction1 = new Fraction ( numerator1,  denominator1);

    fraction2 = new Fraction ( numerator2,  denominator2);
```

---

refers to

---

```
class Fraction{
public int numerator;
public int denominator;

public Fraction( int n, int d )
{
    this.numerator = n;

    this.denominator = d;
}

public Fraction()
{
    this.numerator = 1;

    this.denominator = 2;
}
```

}

From my understanding, I have taken a String input from the command line.

I've then split the String to identify the inputs that I want to set as integers.

Then I've used `int numerator1 = Integer.parseInt(fraction1[0]);` etc

to convert the String to an integer.

Then, from what I understand, I've then taken the integers I've created, and put them in the parameters for my object creation

```
fraction1 = new Fraction(numerator1, denominator1);

fraction2 = new Fraction(numerator2, denominator2);
```

so that I can pass them down to my Fraction class and then assign those to the class instance variables.

Instead of this all working, I get the following errors:

```
ArithmeticWithFractions.java:42: error: incompatible types: Fraction cannot be converted to String
                fraction1 = new Fraction ( numerator1,  denominator1);
                            ^
ArithmeticWithFractions.java:44: error: incompatible types: Fraction cannot be converted to String
                fraction2 = new Fraction ( numerator2,  denominator2);
                            ^
ArithmeticWithFractions.java:47: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Fraction
                Calculator calculator = new Calculator(fraction1, fraction2);
```

What in tarnation is going on?

I thought I converted the Strings to integers with the `parseInt`.

Gah!

Comment: See your declaration part `String fraction1 = args[0];`. As the `fraction1` and `fraction2` is declared as string, you can't assign `Fraction` class object to it.

Comment: see this `String fraction1` - it is saying that `fraction1` is a String.  See this `fraction1 = new Fraction` - it is trying to assign a Fraction to the String

Comment: If you want to assign it to class level variable than use like `this.fraction1 = new Fraction ( numerator1,  denominator1);`

Comment: It's a really bad idea to use the same name for two different variables that are accessible from the same place.  Your `String` variable called `fraction1` hides your `Fraction` variable called `fraction1`.  Maybe use different names for the `String`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see your code, you have declared the `fraction1` and `fraction2` twice. One is local variable that is string and another is class level variable that is of type `Fraction`.

By default java used lowest scoped variable. So in your case the local variable is in picture so your are getting incompatible error.

If you want to use class level variables than you need to use it like below.

```
ArithmeticWithFractions.fraction1 = new Fraction ( numerator1,  denominator1);
ArithmeticWithFractions.fraction2 = new Fraction ( numerator2,  denominator2);
```

And same you need to do while passing it to `Calculator` constructor.

```
Calculator calculator = new Calculator(ArithmeticWithFractions.fraction1, ArithmeticWithFractions.fraction2);
```

Comment: That seems to have worked. That also makes sense. Local variables take precedence, so I needed to make sure I worked with the class variables (right?) and I do that by referencing them with:

    ArithmeticWithFractions.fraction1 = new Fraction (numerator1, denominator1);